# Running my work webapp locally but cant access the correct site

Tags: python, django, localhost

I have been trying to get a Django webapp run in local. What I have done was set my `debug = True` and basically carried my `settings.py` file over from my test server. I finally got my  `python manage.py runserver [::]:8000` to run smoothly without errors. The problem that I am now having is that I cant access the correct idea.

Sorry for any incorrect terms but lets say my application is at three links www.webapp.com, www.buying.webapp.com and www.selling.webapp.com where the SITE_IDs are 1,2,3. I have learned to use localhost:8000 to access webapps before but that was with my simpler webapps.

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you.

EDIT:
I followed `DOMAINS_URLCONF` and found this

```
class SubdomainMiddleware:
    """ Make the subdomain publicly available to classes """

    def process_request(self, request):
        domain_parts = request.get_host().split('.')
        if (len(domain_parts) > 2):
            subdomain = domain_parts[0]
            if (subdomain.lower() == 'www'):
                subdomain = None
            domain = '.'.join(domain_parts[1:])
        else:
            subdomain = None
            domain = request.get_host()
#         if subdomain in settings.DOMAINS_URLCONF:
#             request.__setattr__('urlconf',settings.DOMAINS_URLCONF[subdomain])
        try:
            current_site = Site.objects.get(domain=request.get_host())
        except Site.DoesNotExist:
            current_site = Site.objects.get(id=settings.SITE_ID)

        request.current_site = current_site
        #settings.SITE_ID = current_site.id
        request.subdomain = subdomain
        request.domain = domain
```

Comment: How does the routing on those subdomains work?

Comment: Is your webapp running on 127.0.0.1:8000 or localhost:8000 ?

Comment: @Sayse it looks like they are in my settings.py under `DOMAINS_URLCONF`. 
@Manumathew They both connect when I try to connect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that to work, you simply need different domains on your local machine. That can be simply achieved by editing your local `/etc/hosts` file (on windows it is `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`). Simply add this line in it:

```
127.0.0.1     buying.x.localhost selling.x.localhost
```

Update:

After seeing your middleware code, there is one more caveat: local domains for buying and selling should have at least 3 parts. I've just added `.x` in the middle of domains above, so it should be parsed correctly by this middleware. You can structure those urls as you wish, but they have to have at least 3 parts and the first part has to match one of the subdomains of your project.

After doing this, if you type just `localhost:8000` in the address bar of your browser, you should see the main page, by entering `buying.x.localhost:8000` you will see the content of `buying.` subdomain and by entering `selling.x.localhost:8000` you will see content of `selling.` subdomain.

Comment: Hmm So I followed `DOMAINS_URLCONF` and it doesn't look like its being used. I Found the Middleware for the subdomain up in my edit. Does this look familiar

Comment: I think that it should work without touching `DOMAINS_URLCONF` at all.

Comment: This is a terrible question, but if I had both on there then how would I know which domain I am trying to reach?